# Google console API chart analysis issue

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

How to find total requests per day for a particular API while analysing chart in Google console? It shows only average requests not total. And also I have doubt about counts displayed there. What is count? and how is it calculated?

[image: Click to see image regarding this.]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Where have I mentioned "urgent" in my question?Can you show me ? @halfer

Comment: See the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48022355/revisions), which contains "please help me as soon as possible". I edited the question on 29th Dec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter is missing because of which you are not getting count for per day.
If you look at your attached screenshot then selected section is **6 hours** instead try selecting **1 day** and then check **Count**. This will give you total Requests per day for a particular API.

And to know particular API usage count then select your api method from dropdown present as **All API Methods**

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Yup Now I got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Khyati_StackOverflow can you please accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: Why not :) @Nikhil Lotke